# How doluminosity emails get Gmail to show a "tick" in the subject line?

Tags: gmail

My latest luminosity email has a tick in the subject line like this:

[image]

Is it a new feature of Gmail? if so, what is it or am i missing summing?

I see it works in Outlook.com as well, the message source has "=E2=9C=94 Sleep's secrets to brain health:" in the subject line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add text to an email's subject line that show up as symbols. similar to the way smiley's work in text messages now.

I know you don't believe me.

[here's](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/674) a link showing you how.

Or it could be black magic.

Comment: Yeah - found out all the coll UTF8 codes to do it here - http://thisthingiscrazy.com/a-collection-of-email-subject-utf-8-images/

Answer (score 1):

May be the sender of the Mail Used unicode characters in Email Subject.

[image]